# Meteor: How do i make Updating Meteor.user fields reactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a set of objects called 'categories' which have posts in them that belong to that category. A user is able to 'follow' a category by clicking a button that takes the data within that category object, most importantly the posts puts them in a field within Meteor.users. As it stands, the user only gets the posts that were available at the when the user clicked the button.

How do i make it so that when they 'follow' a category, any new posts that come in later, after the click event has already been done, will automatically be pushed to their user data. In other words, how do make this process reactive?

client/categories.js

```
Template.CategoriesMain.events({
  'click .toggle-category': function(e){
          var ob = $(e.target).parent().find("div").text();
          var id = $.makeArray( ob );
          console.log(id);

          e.preventDefault();
          Meteor.call('addingCategory', id, function(error, user){ console.log(id)});
      }
});
```

server/categories.js

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'name': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

could i do something with autorun? to the tune of this?

```
Template.CategoriesMain.events({
  'click .toggle-category': function(e){
    autorun(function() { 

          var ob = $(e.target).parent().find("div").text();
          var id = $.makeArray( ob );
          console.log(id);

          e.preventDefault();
          Meteor.call('addingCategory', id, function(error, user){ console.log(id)});
      }

  });    
});
```

Comment: Hm ... it does not depend on the users field. You just have to publish your posts collection and set the filter by users.categories. So when you subscribe to the posts on the client, everytime a new post within that categories is added, it is automatically also published to the client. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Hi @TomFreudenberg thank you for responding, but i'm afraid i don't understand what you mean. as it stands, i have a collection that publishes the posts and updates properly to the client, but when it comes to me populating the meteor.user it will not work

Answer (score 0):

can't get it currently but try

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'name': 1}});
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  this.ready();

});
```